# Undefined property: App\Cart::$totalPrice

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

Hello I am making a cart but when I click on add to cart link then it says:

> Undefined property: App\Cart::$totalPrice

Error:  https://ibb.co/ysB5CfG

model:

```
  <?php

  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Cart
  {
private $contents;
private $totalQty;
private $contentsPrice;

public function __construct($oldCart){
    if ($oldCart) {
        $this->contents = $oldCart->contents;
        $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
        $this->totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;
    }
}

public function addProduct($product, $qty){
    $products = ['qty' => 0, 'price' => $product->price, 'product' => $product];
    if ($this->contents) {
        if (array_key_exists($product->slug, $this->contents)) {
            $product = $this->contents[$product->slug];
        }
    }

    $products['qty'] +=$qty;
    $products['price'] +=$product->price * $product['qty'];
    $this->contents[$product->slug] = $product;
    $this->totalQty+=$qty;
    $this->totalPrice += $product->price;
}

public function getContents()
{
    return $this->contents;
}
public function getTotalQty()
{
    return $this->totalQty;
}
public function getTotalPrice()
{
    return $this->totalPrice;
}
}
```

controller:

```
   public function cart()
{
    if (!Session::has('cart')) {
        return view('products.cart');
    }
    $cart = Session::has('cart');
    return view('product.cart', compact('cart'));
}

public function addToCart(Product $product, Request $request, $qty= null)
{
    if(empty(Auth::user()->email)){
        $data['email'] = '';    
    }else{
        $data['email'] = Auth::user()->email;
    }

    $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
    $qty = $request->qty ? $request->qty : 1;
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->addProduct($product, $qty);
    Session::put('cart', $cart);

    return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success', 'Product $product->title has been successfully added to Cart');
  }
```

routes:

```
  Route::get('cart', 'Admin\ProductController@cart')->name('product.cart');

  // Add to cart
  Route::get('/addToCart/{product}/{qty?}', 'Admin\ProductController@addToCart')->name('addToCart');
```

Comment: In your model file define a private class `private $contentsPrice;`. But not define `private $totalPrice`. So I think that is mistake.

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya thnx but now its not redirecting to cart page ,, it only reloading th products-detail page ,, means it refreshs its own page

Comment: I think you should use `return redirect()->route('product.cart');` instead of redirect back in controller file. But can you check product successfully added on a cart?

Comment: I have written this in the cart page   if(isset($cart) && $cart->getContents()) //other code    else
  <p class="alert alert-danger">No Products in the Cart <a href="{{route('products.all')}}">Buy Some Products</a></p>
 endif

Comment: That is why I told you to check the product added in the cart or not.

Comment: Call to a member function getContents() on boolean (View: \resources\views\product\cart.blade.php)

Comment: You should dump `$cart` on view file. `var_dump($cart)`.

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya I write it here @if(isset($cart) && $cart->getContents())
var_dump($cart);  and most other places but nthing is happening

Comment: What is your exact URL for add to cart for a product?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please use `$cart = Session::get('cart');` method.

Comment: If you wish to get the value of a `product_name` then the input field is needed. My suggestion is to use input filed type `hidden`. And product name shows the only label like `<p>{{ $product->product_name }}</p>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should use `get()` methods in cart() function in controller file.**

```
public function cart()
{
  if (!Session::has('cart')) {
    return view('products.cart');
  }
  $cart = Session::get('cart');
  return view('product.cart', compact('cart'));
}
```